# Recursively unpack list into elements

Tags: recursion, f#, mutable

I have a list and would like to return each element from it individually. Basically like popping from a stack. For example:

```
let rnd = new System.Random()
let rnds = List.init 10 (fun _ -> rnd.Next(100))
List.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A"x ) rnds
```

However instead of iterating, I would actually like to return each integer one after the other until the list is empty. So basically something along the lines of:

```
List.head(rnds)
List.head(List.tail(rnds))
List.head(List.tail(List.tail(rnds)))
List.head(List.tail(List.tail(List.tail(List.tail(rnds)))))
```

Unfortunately my attempts at a recursive solution or even better something using fold or scan were unsuccessful. For example this just returns the list (same as map).

```
let pop3 (rnds:int list) =
    let rec pop3' rnds acc =
        match rnds with
        | head :: tail -> List.tail(tail)
        | [] -> acc
    pop3' [] rnds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good oppurtunity for a class

```
type unpacker(l) = 
    let mutable li = l
    member x.get() = 
        match li with
        |h::t -> li<-t;h
        |_ -> failwith "nothing left to return"
```

Comment: So I would use it like:  `let xx = unpacker(rnds)`  `xx.get()`  or ` [for i in 1..5 -> xx.get()]`  I added  `override this.ToString() = sprintf "%A" l`  to make it a bit more user friendly.

Answer (score 5):

Would `uncons` do what you need?

```
let uncons = function h::t -> Some (h, t) | [] -> None
```

You can use it to 'pop' the head of a list:

```
> rnds |> uncons;;
val it : (int * int list) option =
  Some (66, [17; 93; 33; 17; 21; 1; 49; 5; 96])
```

You can repeat this:

```
> rnds |> uncons |> Option.bind (snd >> uncons);;
val it : (int * int list) option = Some (17, [93; 33; 17; 21; 1; 49; 5; 96])
> rnds |> uncons |> Option.bind (snd >> uncons) |> Option.bind (snd >> uncons);;
val it : (int * int list) option = Some (93, [33; 17; 21; 1; 49; 5; 96])
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, a very interesting solution as well. Thanks very much.